# React-select creatable - only allow one created option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-select

I am using [react-select](https://react-select.com/creatable) and the creatable function that allows you to create a new select option - just type in the select/input field on [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o49kjl09j9).

I want to put a check in that only allows one creatable option to be made at one time, the next created option removes and supersedes the previous. At the moment yo can create an infinite amount.

This is the part that handles the created option so guess I need to add some sort of rule to only allow one option here.

Any help appreciated.

```
  handleCreate = input => (inputValue: any) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { options } = this.state;
      const newOption = createOption(inputValue);
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        options: [...options, newOption],
        value: newOption
      });
      input.onChange(newOption);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/o49kjl09j9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is storing the index of the new option, check if there is an index stored and if so replace this value by the new one like the following code:

```
state = {
    value: this.props.options[0],
    options: this.props.options,
    hasCreatedOption: false
  };
  handleCreate = input => (inputValue: any) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { options } = this.state;
      const newOption = createOption(inputValue);
      let hasCreatedOption = false;

      if (this.state.hasCreatedOption) {
        options[this.state.hasCreatedOption] = newOption;
      } else {
        options.push(newOption);
      }
      hasCreatedOption = options.length - 1;

      this.setState({
        hasCreatedOption,
        isLoading: false,
        options: [...options],
        value: newOption
      });
      input.onChange(newOption);
    }, 1000);
  };
```

[Here a live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ly7o3olj3z).

Comment: Your example seems to work at first however it only does add a new option on every other created option. e.g. type in 3 custom options. the 3rd will display

Comment: @TomRudge sorry for the mistake, I have updated my code to fix this bug.

Comment: thanks for the update - here is another problem that links both of your previous answers up - this is the final jigsaw... can you help please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261367/handling-map-and-if-else-statement-for-react-render-using-react-select @Laura